# is making an ajax POST request to a server with a different domain and basic auth impossible?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, basic-authentication, preflight

I am trying to make a POST request to a server with a different domain, that requires basic authentication.

I have tried every combination of beforeSend and withCredentials, but the basic auth headers are never sent through in the OPTIONS preflight request.

```
 $.ajax({
      url: anotherdomain,
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType:'json',
      xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true
      },
      crossDomain: true,
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic *');
          xhr.withCredentials = true;        
      }
```

The only way i can seem to get this request to succeed is by setting dataType to 'jsonp', or setting the request 'type' to a GET.

Is the only solution to this problem to remove the Basic Auth requirement from the anotherdomain server for OPTIONS requests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to also  allow headers on the server:
Here is a php example (this is open for request for all origins, I suggest you limit it only to the site generating the ajax):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```